# Is there a good single word for "creating something by accident"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

If somebody unintentionally creates or invents something, they ... it?

I am wondering if there is a single verb (or possibly verb-with-preposition, see examples 2 and 3 below) which catches this meaning.

A little search and thinking bring up the following options:

1. concoct
2. rustle up
3. knock up (supposedly British, supposedly also having the meaning "to impregnate" which would make it a bad choice)

If you have a better one, please share, or please let me know which of the above might fit best.

Edit, Oct 4: As per request, here are two example sentences.

- Not being quite awake yet, Sondra poured some cocoa powder into her cup of tea. After she realized what she had done, she actually took a sip, thinking that maybe she had [XXX]ed a fancy new beverage. She had not.
- The proofreader, having no understanding of the contents of the paper, suggested different word orders for all sentences in the second paragraph. By doing this, he [XXX]ed the worst possible way of describing the machinery in question.

Comment: Your examples are more to do with improvisation *with* intent. True accidents are somewhat less common, like the ship's propeller being "invented" when a long auger used to propel a boat upstream in shallow water by digging into the bottom  snapped off short. The long version didn't push the boat through the water - only over the bottom - but the broken-off one did!

Comment: Isn't this usually called a discovery?

Comment: Your question @ "discovery" is honestly a good one. We reserve a kind of reverence and intent in "discover". I know what it literally means but it doesn't connote exactly what Torsten is after. "Discover" oddly lacks emphasis on "accident" as well as "created". Discoveries can be intentional (scientist with well-reasoned hypotheses) or unintentional (or at least obscured). They can also be found rather than created and the word is often used in a context of appraisal whereas Torsten's situation could be negative. I don't know a word that does all that but it also seems like it exists.

Comment: That being said, "discover" is probably the best option (especially if it's allowed to be more ambiguous and on the positive side).

Comment: The two senses of "knock up" are usually easy to distinguish by context, so not a particularly bad choice - it takes some effort to deliberately use as a pun.  But all three suggestions involve creativity, which is not what you want.

Comment: A detailed example sentence would go a long way towards clarifying the actual meaning you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps too simple to be an answer, but "recognize" would fit in some cases. It puts the emphasis on realizing that an unexpected result has (positive or negative) importance, and that distinguishes serendipity from dumb luck.

Comment: @barbecue: See added examples.

Answer (score 20):

*Fluke*:

> verb: achieve (something) by luck rather than skill ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=fluke%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsbDx_Fh1ehlCp919d24Q-9W0wDEmw%3A1664653423324&source=hp&ei=b5g4Y_-7EZipgAbNoar4BA&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYzimf4lgae4edqzKo_3qPJIB2MQ4y3Nt&oq=fluke&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIFCAAQkQIyBwgAELEDEEMyEAguELEDEMcBENEDENQCEEMyCgguELEDENQCEEMyBAguEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyCwgAEIAEELEDEIMBMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATIICC4QgAQQsQM6BAgjECc6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOhAILhCxAxCDARDHARDRAxBDOgcILhDUAhBDOgUIABCABFAAWN8JYO8iaABwAHgAgAGFAYgBlQSSAQMzLjKYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz))

It's informal and more often used as a noun.

Note that *concoct* involves *[using skill or ingenuity](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/concoct.html)*, so it does not really fit.

As an aside, it may be of interest that such discoveries or inventions are called ***serendipities***:

> The term "***serendipity***" is often applied to *inventions made by chance rather than intent*. Andrew Smith, editor of The Oxford Companion to American Food and Drink, has speculated that *most everyday products had serendipitous roots*, with many early ones related to animals. The origin of cheese, for example, possibly originated in the nomad practice of storing milk in the stomach of a dead camel that was attached to the saddle of a live one, thereby mixing rennet from the stomach with the milk stored within. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serendipity#:%7E:text=The%20term%20%22serendipity%22%20is%20often,by%20chance%20rather%20than%20intent.))

Here is an interesting article about such finds:

> *[Science and serendipity: famous accidental discoveries](https://newhumanist.org.uk/articles/4852/science-and-serendipity-famous-accidental-discoveries)*

There is no verb for *serendipity*, though. Yet.

Comment: I would recommend nobody ever use *fluke* as a verb.  It sounds flukin’ horrible.

Comment: Excellent answer that covers the two fitting words.

Comment: @Jim, "fluked it" is [gaining popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluked+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Jim: *fluke* as a verb was standard schoolyard slang when I was growing up (Northern England in the ’90s).  But it was about *achieving* something not creating something — typically a stroke of luck in a game, e.g. in pool, sinking a ball with a double rebound.

Comment: "and more often used as a noun." Yeah, that's the first word that came to mind when I saw the question but I dismissed it because I always thought it was a noun only! The [Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fluke) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fluke) dictionaries seem to agree, but now I'm not sure. If you have a dictionary reference and sentence examples, would be great! Is it just a verb in slang? Couldn't find that in the Urban dictionary either...

Comment: @Nagev OxfordL, of which I provided the link, lists it as a verb. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fluked%20it%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2015,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) are some examples.

Comment: @Nagev: One of the examples in @ fev’s search is the [New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://www.routledge.com/The-New-Partridge-Dictionary-of-Slang-and-Unconventional-English/Dalzell-Victor/p/book/9780367570491) (full content unfortunately not available online), which clearly lists it as a verb. You can also find it on Urban Dictionary if you go to the third page of entries for *fluke* — it just gets crowded out from the first page by the more colourful and less regionally-specific senses.

Comment: You can then of course verify the correctness of your fluked invention with a [Fluke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fluke_115_multimeter.jpg) by [Fluke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Fluke).

Comment: I saw the link right after I posted my comment and decided to leave it in case you had other references, since that one is tied to Google. @PLL thanks, I had a look at [the third page](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fluke&page=3) and it's defined as a verb to mean "win against the odds" with noun examples. But anyway, it's not that uncommon to use nouns as verbs in casual English, so it makes sense. It is also defined as a verb on [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fluke): "to gain, make, or hit by a fluke".  Can't wait to fluke something so I get to use it!

Comment: nouns as verbs, hence "have I just serendipitied it"? geesh, but I think it sounds a bit better than "fluked it" :)

Comment: Fluke is a verb used in Snooker all the time.  And of course, there's the noun too.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting suggestion. How well, you think, would it fit into either of the two example sentences I have added?

Comment: In your first example it fits very well, and the fact that "fluke" is informal, matches the register of her thought. Your second sentence bears a negative connotation, which doesn't fit normally with "fluke". For some reason, maybe because the examples were not there at the beginning, I assumed that you meant positive inventions. However, "fluke" can work in the second sentence, as it will be perceived as used _ironically_, meaning the contrary of what you say.

Comment: If you say "he invented/came up with the worst possible way", you express a little irony, by attributing effort and skill to a bad outcome. The fact that it is unintentional, a bad accident, is clear enough from the context. In fact, your own suggestion _**concoct**_, may be the best option for a negative context. It fits perfectly your second sentence.

Comment: Just came across [_**conjure**_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conjure) : "to make something appear by magic, or as if by magic". That would be an excellent variant for your second sentence, although it seems far from the meaning you give, if you take it literally.  Ironically, it is spot on!

Answer (score 18):

*Serendipity* is

> the faculty or phenomenon of finding valuable or agreeable things not sought for

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serendipity)

Also, *fortuitous*.

> coming or happening by a lucky chance

You could use the adjective/adverb form of either to modify words such as discovery or invention.

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortuitous)

Answer (score 13):

This is harder than I first thought (like most things).

As you identified, there seem to be three parts:

- Created
- Unintended
- Positive *or* negative.

I'm not sure I can think of one that does all this so you might have to pick a word that focusses on one or two more than the other(s).

Your options so far suggest you want something more on the created and positive/neutral side (considering, also, your comment on "knocked up").

If not, this is a good option:

*Stumble upon*

> to discover or meet with accidentally or unexpectedly (usually followed by on, upon, or across): *They stumbled on a little village.* ([Dictionary.com definition 5](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stumble))

It emphasises more the unintended aspect and doesn't literally mean "created" but can in a colloquial/ironic/humorously self-deprecating way (e.g. "I stumbled upon a great formula for root beer").

Comment: "Stumbled upon" implies that there was an intended destination (or need), but that the path taken was "accidental".  One can stumble either because they lack the strength to continue (the weary hiker stumbled into the tent), or because an unexpected obstacle (the refreshed hiker stepped out of the tent and stumbled over a large root covered by fallen leaves).   I prefer "upon" since it sounds slightly archaic, and better fits the idiom as I learned it.

Comment: I also prefer "upon", because it evokes the idea of tripping over conceptually and onomatopoetically. I agree it's hard to find a word that avoids all issues. The accident is what I meant by "unintended", but I'm trying to make allowances for the shades and distinctions about which bits are intended. (I'm getting the sense you read my earlier comment.) An intended destination is part of OP's request, though (or needs clarification): how does one *create* something without intent? There must be an initial intention in whichever direction.

Comment: 'Stumbled upon'? They made a whole village by mistake?

Comment: It doesn't mean "created". See right after the example. I also said it wouldn't serve the same purpose beforehand. Often one choice or another sacrifices one of the parts OP requested. But, like most phrases in language, this *can* be used to mean "created" metaphorically, depending on the situation. Village isn't likely to be one.

Answer (score 12):

I went to Roget's Thesaurus for this, and in particular entry **484 (Discovery)**.

There are some good options there; the ones I think are a good fit are:

- **happen upon**
- **stumble upon**
- **strike (upon)**
- **hit upon**

In all cases, "on" could be used in place of "upon", of course.

Comment: All good suggestions. Just be aware that "[hit on (someone)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/hit-on)" (instead of some*thing*)  has a very different meaning.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yeah, but provided the object of that sentence is *not* a person, it would be pretty well understood to have the intended meaning.

Comment: I like all of these, thank you. I have added two example sentences in the question. For the second example sentence, I would intutively choose "hit upon", for the first one maybe more "struck upon" or "stumble upon", although I have no clear reason why. What do you think?

Answer (score 8):

This phrasal verb comes close

[Luck into](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luck%20into) (Merriam Webster Dictionary):  to find or get (something) seemingly because of good luck.

"**By-product**" nearly captures "**Created something by accident**".

[By-product](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/by-product) (Wiktionary) A secondary product; something made incidentally during the production of something else.

P.S. There is a subtle difference between "incidentally" and "accidentally".

[Incidentally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incidentally):(Wiktionary)  (manner) In an incidental manner; not of central or critical importance: **by chance; in an unplanned way**:
(speech act, conjunctive) parenthetically, by the way. It's the [8240](http://corpus.leeds.ac.uk/frqc/internet-en.num)th most commonly used word in English.

[Accidentally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accidentally):(Wiktionary)  In an accidental manner; **unexpectedly; by chance**; casually; **fortuitously: unintentionally**. It's the [7532](http://corpus.leeds.ac.uk/frqc/internet-en.num)th most commonly used word in English.

The parts in bold have the meaning "in an unplanned or unexpected way".

Comment: "By product" does not suggest "created by accident" at all. It simply refers to the production of something the production of which is not the primary purpose of the process. E.g., "pollutants are a by-product of the internal combustion engine", or "illness is a by-product of overcrowded housing". "Incidentally" does not mean "accidentally".

Comment: You made this comment "Incidentally" does not mean "accidentally". I want to know the full import. You were implying, a)That this forum member does not re-read his post before posting, b)That this forum member does not know the difference between "Incidentally" and "accidentally".

Comment: I'm afraid you're reading intent into my comment that simply isn't there.

Comment: You have nicely phrased your comment. I will be using that in future. "Incidentally' and "accidentally" are commonly used words. Anyone moderately versed in English know the difference between them. I have edited my answer to be more comprehensive and more to the point so as to be to be not—misread and miscomprehended.

Answer (score 2):

A common expression for this (or any unforeseen felicitous result) is **happy accident**.  [Collins (COBUILD) has examples of usage,](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/happy-accident) including, from the *Sunday Times*:

> As with many medical breakthroughs, his interest in the subject started through a happy accident.

Answer (score 1):

The word order makes this hard.  If I "(verb)" something, how can that be unintentional yet have a specific outcome?  If you would be willing to reverse the order to "it "(verb)" them" and allow a preposition, a number of possibilities open up:
came to, settled upon, revealed itself to, hit, emanated from...

I know, that's cheating.  The best I could come up with in original form:
The boss's departure **released** a torrent of new creativity.
By tripping on a loose rock, I **triggered** a landslide.
For lack of ingredients, I **blundered into** a new recipe.

Comment: It wasn't there when you wrote your answer, but two examples were added recently to the question, and I think the first one nails the idea, I'm not a native speaker, but this short story feels very natural, and that's definitely something I could try to say and get stuck on a missing word in the same moment. Using word order reversal trick in this case feels very cumbersome.